# How good Adobe Spry comparing to JQuery and what are perspectives

Tags: jquery, adobe, spry

It seems JQuery, its plugins and UI has largest popularity among JS platforms. I love and use Adobe technology stack every day, I wonder if Adobe Spry will be good addition to skill set. 
Is it good enough comparing to JQuery ? Spry development is not moving forward fast and there's not much information about it, does it have future ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely not.  Proprietary frameworks like Spry are not going to be able to beat the simplicity, openness and general intelligence of compatibility-oriented libraries like jQuery.  Many developers that were once Flash-heavy (myself included), build entire applications in jQuery every day.  It's blazingly fast, brilliantly written and makes use of the more "magical" language features in Javascript (currying,closures,etc.).

Try it, you'll like it ;)